# Current and next props are the same in componentWillReceiveProps call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am updating my redux store variables and pass them as props to a component but in this piece of code both current and next props are the same, equal to new ones when I change them via dispatch from outside.

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    console.log(this.props.data);
    console.log(nextProps.data);
}
```

Why does it happen so? Should they be different at all if changed via dispatch?

Comment: Are you calling dispatch asynchronously? If so maybe that could part of it. Also, IIFC componentWillReceiveProps only has nextProps as argument.

Comment: I don't think there is any async stuff running. I have a select box, which makes the store update instantly via an action.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov If `componentWillReceiveProps` is being called multiple times after dispatch action, then at least one time it must have logged different current and next props.

Comment: I don't see anything like that, it behaves as described just from the start.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> Note that **React may call this method even if the props have not
>   changed**, so make sure to compare the current and next values if you
>   only want to handle changes. **This may occur when the parent component
>   causes your component to re-render**.

So you should be seeing at least one set of different props (the actual change) but not necessarily on every log.

Comment: My issue is I see new values for both `this.props.data` and `nextProps.data`. So data changes properly, but for some reason I don't see current values which should be before change.

Comment: Is the component already mounted when you dispatch the change? Because `componentWillReceiveProps` does not trigger on mounting, so it could be there that the props are changing. Try logging on `componentWillMount` too.

Comment: Tried that, and also tried to look at `componentWillReceiveProps` of the parent root container, that one shows both next and current props as equal to next props.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly your problem then, but to cover everything: have you tried tracking action dispatchs with `redux-logger`? Are you sure you're comparing the same prop that you're updating? (I've been guilty of that..). Also, could you edit in the question the related containers?

Answer (score 1):

I found the core of the problem.

I used this to clone my current state in a reducer:

```
export const cloneDeep = (state) => ({...state});
```

Which seemed to be mutating current state.
I replaced it with this one:

```
export const cloneDeep = (state) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Which doesn't do any changes to current state and current props are not equal to nextProps now if changed.

Comment: the first version of that code is a shallow clone, the second one is creating a full new version, however, I would be wary to use it, depending on what the state would contain, it could be a very expensive call, and can be break with circular references

Comment: Should first version mutate current state and thus cause the problem I had?

Comment: Well, yeah, as it is a shallow clone, any reference properties the state has, gets copied in the new object (see this thing: https://jsfiddle.net/hejfw8t1/)